# jQuery add variable to selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing an ID to a selector, but somehow it doesn't work. When I hardcode it, then it works. Below is my script and the various ways I have tried. :

```
 jQuery("li.<?php echo slugify($catId); ?>").closest("ul").closest("li").addClass("active");
```

When I view in console, the script above echoes out the $catId correctly but it just doesn't work.
Then I tried this :-

```
var catId='<?php echo $catId; ?>';
jQuery("li."+catId).closest("ul").closest("li").addClass("active");
```

In the console, the variable catId wasn't printed out at all. It shows ("li."+catId) in the console.

Then I tried converting it to string and pass it to the selector like this :

```
var catString = catId.toString();
```

It doesn't work either. I hardcode the catId directly to the line and it works just fine.

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `jQuery("li."+catId+"")`

Comment: @AdamAzad thanks for your reply. I just tried but it didn't work too. The console shows jQuery("li."+catId+"") directly, without the value of the variable.

Comment: or try `var catId='.'+'<?php echo $catId; ?>'; jQuery('li'+catId). ...`

Comment: @Mi-Creativity thanks for your reply. It didn't work too, I wonder why the value of the variable is not displayed in the selector.

Comment: tried to `console.log(catId)`?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity ahh.. it printed out the value, but in the selector it's not showing the value.

Comment: Please try to add fiddle and desired result.

Comment: If the `$catId` has any special characters (` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\]^{|}~`), then they need to be escaped before the jQuery selector will work ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).

Comment: @Mottie It only has a hypen (-).

Comment: Is your code wrapped by a `$(function(){ /* code here */ });` (aka document ready function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it!!! 
It's just moving the whole `<script></script>` to after the `<li> </li>`
Basically the placement of the script causes the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying the above snippets your HTML should look like this

```
<li class="<?php echo slugify($catId); ?>"> ....
```

And you shouldn't be associating them to id attribute

Comment: Yup, I did put slugify for the class.

Comment: if you dont mind please share your snippet for the html

Comment: sure! It's a loop actually. Thus, here is how I assign the class to the li.
 <li class="<?=slugify($child->getId());?>">

Comment: but in your code above you are passing var catId='<?php echo $catId; ?>'; and it might create problems if there are any space or conversions. use slugify uniformly and give it a try

Comment: I tried to put in slugify too, but it gives me the same result. and I checked there's no spacing either.